# rails Geocoder change unit to km

Tags: ruby-on-rails, location

I try to change the unit from mils to KM. I just learn from railscast.com
here is the link http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder
I am try tu pu this code into the location controller file,but it's dose work.

```
Location.near(params[:search], 50, {:order => :distance, :units => :km})
```

[image]

Comment: Not a direct solution, but you can divide kilometers by 1.6 to get miles.

Comment: I just checked the source of the `Geocoder`gem and :km should work. What is the exact error message?

Comment: I dont get any error message. just dont change it to KM.I dont know why.

Comment: Actually I think the `:units => :km`that you passed to the `near`method worked (it returns all the locations that are situated 50km from the passed in location). It's just that the results are shown in miles, may be you could specify that you want to display the results in :km as well.

Comment: I have just read the source for the location/show.html.erb file. I suppose that you saw that 'miles' is hard coded?

Comment: no,I change to km. when I click the show it will show the as km on web page.but it's not real. that distance 0.29 miles convert to km 0.46671 km.